# chrome.cookies.set doesn't even run

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The following code doesn't work for some reason:

Background.js

```
alert("1");
chrome.cookies.set({ url: "https://mywebsite.com", name: "SuperDuperTest" });
alert("2");
```

manifest.json

> "permissions": [ "notifications", "https://mywebsite.com",
>   "cookies", "http://* /* ", "https://* / * "  ],

Only alert("1"); ever fires. Alert 2 never does, why isn't my chrome cookies firing at all?

Comment: What does the javascript console say?

Comment: I can't see any `chrome.cookies` in my console. Is that a specialty just for extensions?

Comment: Yeah mine is blank too, thats why I'm using alerts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where are looking to check whether your cookie is set or not?
Please use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

### Sample Code

#### manifest.json

Registered background page and given permissions for Cookies API.

```
{
    "name": "Cookie API Demo",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448039/chrome-cookies-set-doesnt-even-run",
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

#### background.js

Trivial code to set cookie for `cookies.html` page

```
chrome.cookies.set({
    "name": "Sample1",
    "url": "http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html",
    "value": "Dummy Data"
}, function (cookie) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
    console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

## Output

Go to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html and open developer tools as shown here, you can see cookie is being set!.

[Click for Large Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYahW.png)

[image]

## Further Debugging

If this sample code does not work, what are values of `chrome.extension.lastError` and `chrome.runtime.lastError`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declared the cookies permission.

> To use the cookies API, you must declare the "cookies" permission in
>   your manifest, along with host permissions for any hosts whose cookies
>   you want to access. For example:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://*.google.com"
  ],
  ...
}
```

source: [developer.chrome.com](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html)

Comment: I have, I have copied my manifest into the question post that you can read above.